# Google Sync is destroying my bookmarks?

Tags: google-chrome, chrome-bookmarks

How do I see how many and which devices my Google account is syncing with?

I clicked the new icon in the upper right of chrome and logged in and synced. First off this makes no sense because I signed into Chrome a long time ago.

Anyway I logged in and it destroyed my bookmarks.

Set them back to how they were months ago.

Luckily I was able to grab bookmarks.bak and replace bookmarks with it.

How do I avoid this happening? Why did this happen? I'm not aware of having any other devices that I've logged into so I have no idea what it was syncing with that destroyed the bookmarks.

I am very confused as to how this syncing is working. It seems like you can sign into Chrome and that is completely different to signing into syncing with Chrome.

I need to know so I can protect my bookmarks since Google seems intent on making the process incredibly difficult in order to mold every user into the same exact usage pattern.

Comment: Do you have an Android phone?

Comment: No. I don't have a smartphone. No other devices. I logged into another computer with Chrome months and months ago then logged out and let the person who normally uses that computer log back into their account. Did it decide to override the computer I use 100.0 - 1e27 % of the time with one I used once months ago?